# phpmyadmin: export file name template to include table name

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to export few tables in phpmyadmin 4.0.5, and want to include the table name in the saved file name. The default template which comes in is @DATABASE@. Some googling on this suggests that @TABLE@ or **TABLE** should give the table name in the file name template. BUt that's not working. How can it be done if at all it can be done...
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this to work, you have to be in the specific export view of the table.

Choose the table in the left frame, so that in the main frame on top you see a breadcrumb structure like

```
localhost > database name > table name
```

If you click “Export” now, you can use @TABLE@ and it’ll put the table name into the export file name.

If you are just in the database view

```
localhost > database name
```

and click “Export” there – then @TABLE@ won’t work, because you could possibly chose *multiple* tables to export from at the same time, so PMA won’t know what table name to actually use. (It looks like they did not implement any checks at this point to see whether you have chosen only one table or several.)